# The component for route 'AuthLogin' must be a React componet

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

Hello am developing app in React-Native and got below error :

Error : **The component for route 'AuthLogin' must be a React componet.**

My Navigation flow is as below :

```
 const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    ImageDetails: ImageDetailsScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    /* The header config from HomeScreen is now here */
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    },
  });

const AuthTabStack =createTabNavigator(
  {
    AuthLogin : AuthStack,
    InstaLogin: InstagramLoginScreen,
    FacebookLogin: FacebookLoginScreen,
  }
);


const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: LoginScreen,
    Register: RegisterScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    /* The header config from HomeScreen is now here */
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    },
  });

const RootStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Splash: SplashScreen,//Checking user Authntication
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthTabStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Splash',
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

The navigation starts from the RootStack. Contains Splash screen first.
Checking for user login in this screen and accordingly navigating user to either **AppStack** or **AuthTabStack**.

Why this error am I getting ?
Is there any issue with TabNavigator ?

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

==> This is working :

```
const AuthTabStack = createTabNavigator(
  {
    //AuthLogin: AuthStack,
    Login: LoginScreen,
    InstaLogin: InstagramLoginScreen,
    FacebookLogin: FacebookLoginScreen 
  }
);
```

But, **StackNavigator** inside **TabNavigator** has an issue :

```
const AuthTabStack = createTabNavigator(
  {
    AuthLogin: AuthStack,
    //Login: LoginScreen,
    InstaLogin: InstagramLoginScreen,
    FacebookLogin: FacebookLoginScreen 
  }
);
```

===================================================

Comment: Provide AuthLogin file

Comment: Its a key for AuthStack in TabNavigator.    Here ,  :: AuthLogin : AuthStack,

Comment: @JayThummar got it ?

Comment: @JayThummar Issue is there when i am adding stacknavigator named AuthStack inside TabNavigator.

Comment: OK i am on it ..

Comment: @JayThummar And Now ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space after `AuthLogin`, `AuthLogin : AuthStack,` instead of `AuthLogin: AuthStack,`. This could be causing the error.
If this doesn't fix, try `AuthLogin: { screen: AuthStack },`

Comment: No sir, Its not the issue because this is working.. const AuthTabStack = createTabNavigator(
  {
    // AuthLogin: AuthStack,
    Login: LoginScreen,
    InstaLogin: InstagramLoginScreen,
    FacebookLogin: FacebookLoginScreen 
  }
); and this is not working... : const AuthTabStack = createTabNavigator(
  {
    AuthLogin: AuthStack,
    //Login: LoginScreen,
    InstaLogin: InstagramLoginScreen,
    FacebookLogin: FacebookLoginScreen 
  }
);